# No serializer found for class error when I try to create a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I create a web service and it works fine when the return is List
like this:

```
@WebService
public class IndicatorWSImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements IndicatorWS {

@Autowired
private HomeIndicadoresReportService homeIndicadoresReportService;


@Override
public List<String> entidades() {

    homeIndicadoresReportService.buildValuesToGraph(resultMesAtual, selectedEntity, selectedBS, selectedTS,
            selectedFunctionality, filter, false);

    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (EntityIndicatorVO entityIndicatorVO : resultMesAtual) {
        lista.add(entityIndicatorVO.getName());
    }


    return lista;
}

}
```

But when I change the return for the List they can not create this list on the return and come with this error:

```
mai 04, 2017 9:44:20 AM org.apache.axis.Message writeTo
GRAVE: java.io.IOException:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class     com.santander.portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.EntityIndicatorVO in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@6186d47d
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class com.santander.portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.EntityIndicatorVO in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@6186d47d
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1507)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:980)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:734)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArraySerializer.serialize(ArraySerializer.java:425)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1504)
at
```

This are the class with List return:

```
@WebService
public class IndicatorWSImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements IndicatorWS {

@Autowired
private HomeIndicadoresReportService homeIndicadoresReportService;

@Override
public List<EntityIndicatorVO> entidades() {

    homeIndicadoresReportService.buildValuesToGraph(resultMesAtual, selectedEntity, selectedBS, selectedTS,
            selectedFunctionality, filter, false);


    return resultMesAtual;
}

}
```

this is the VO class:

```
public class EntityIndicatorVO extends IndicatorVO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<BSIndicatorVO> bsList;


public EntityIndicatorVO(Long id, String name) {
    super(id, name, 0d);
}

public EntityIndicatorVO() {
}

public void copy(EntityIndicatorVO entityInd) {
    super.copy(entityInd);
    setBsList(entityInd.getBsList());
}

public List<BSIndicatorVO> getBsList() {
    if (bsList == null) {
        bsList = new ArrayList<BSIndicatorVO>();
    }
    return bsList;
}

public void setBsList(List<BSIndicatorVO> bsList) {
    this.bsList = bsList;
}

}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure a serializer in Axis? If not you need to configure it. Axis comes with `BeanSerializer`.

Configuring your bean mapping
[BeanSerializer](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Encoding_Your_Beans_-_the_BeanSerializer)